# Complex combination of AND and OR in strapi (version 4) filtering

Tags: strapi

Hi I want to apply a filter to the strapi api with a combination of AND and OR but I can't seem to get it working.

Situation:
I want to filter on a situation like this

```
(
  (tag OR tag2 OR tag3) AND 
  (
    (title CONTAINSI TEXT_FILTER_HERE) OR 
    (body CONTAINSI TEXT_FILTER_HERE) OR 
    (introduction CONTAINSI TEXT_FILTER_HERE)
  )
)
```

(note that I have abbreviated the tags as that should also be a containsi)

I have tried something like the link below and many others, but this example below will make all of them an OR situation, and I will find too many entries.

```
{{host}/api/blog?sort=publishedAt%3Adesc
&populate=Tags.tags&populate=Image
&pagination[page]=1
&pagination[pageSize]=25
&locale=en
&filters[$or][4][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]=TAG1
&filters[$or][6][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]=TAG2
&filters[$or][8][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]=TAG3
&filters[$or][3][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]=TAG4
&filters[$or][5][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]=TAG5
&filters[$or][7][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]=TAG6
&filters[$or][0][title][$containsi]=FILTER_TEXT_HERE
&filters[$or][2][body][$containsi]=FILTER_TEXT_HERE
&filters[$or][1][introduction][$containsi]=FILTER_TEXT_HERE
```

(made it multiline for readability)

Is it possible to this in strapi?

I can get it to work in an multiple OR situation with just one (1) AND, but not with ((or or) AND (or or)):

```
...
&filters[$or][4][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag1}}
&filters[$or][6][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag2}}
&filters[$or][8][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag3}}
&filters[$or][3][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag4}}
&filters[$or][5][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag5}}
&filters[$or][7][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag6}}
&filters[$and][0][title][$containsi]={{filter}}
```

or

```
...
&filters[$or][4][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag1}}
&filters[$or][6][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag2}}
&filters[$or][8][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag3}}
&filters[$or][3][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag4}}
&filters[$or][5][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag5}}
&filters[$or][7][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag6}}
&filters[title][$containsi]={{filter}}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think I have found the answer. Could not find it anywhere in the documentation (https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#complex-filtering)

```
{{host}}/api/blog?sort=publishedAt%3Adesc
&populate=Tags.tags
&populate=Image
&pagination[page]=1
&pagination[pageSize]=25
&locale=en
&filters[$and][0][$or][0][title][$containsi]={{filter}}
&filters[$and][0][$or][1][introduction][$containsi]={{filter}}
&filters[$and][0][$or][2][body][$containsi]={{filter}}
&filters[$and][1][$or][0][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag1}}
&filters[$and][1][$or][1][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag2}}
&filters[$and][1][$or][2][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag3}}
&filters[$and][1][$or][3][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag4}}
&filters[$and][1][$or][4][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag5}}
&filters[$and][1][$or][5][Tags][tags][Tag][$containsi]={{tag6}}
```

Note the [NUMBER] sections grouping the ANDs and OR's ...
Once you know it, it looks logical :-)