# Strapi - combining AND with OR

Tags: strapi

I am currently trying to get a search feature working where I can search a multi-word string and show results where ALL individual words match ANY of the specified fields.

I'll use a "find a doctor" feature as an example. If I'm looking for a chiropractor in Dallas, I should be able to search "Dallas chiropractor" and get results where "Dallas" matches the City column AND "chiropractor" matches the Specialty column. Or search "Jones Dentist" and have "Jones" match the name and "Dentist" match the specialty to find the "Jones Family Dental" they were looking for.

Previously, I was just using [$or] repeatedly, making a query that looked something like this:

```
"...
&pagination[pageSize]=${20}&pagination[page]=${1}
&filters[$or][0][Name][$containsi]=TERM1
&filters[$or][1][Specialty][$containsi]=TERM1
&filters[$or][2][City][$containsi]=TERM1
&filters[$or][3][Name][$containsi]=TERM2
&filters[$or][4][Specialty][$containsi]=TERM2
&filters[$or][5][City][$containsi]=TERM2"
```

As you can imagine, the results I got were for if ONE search term matched ANY field, which won't do as the more you type the less narrow the search gets.

In trying to figure out some way to get what I need where ALL terms match AT LEAST ONE field of each result, I did some research and this is my code now:
[This is the solution I tried to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056870/complex-combination-of-and-and-or-in-strapi-version-4-filtering)

```
let urlTerms = `&pagination[pageSize]=${pageSize}&pagination[page]=${page}&`;
urlTerms += terms
  .map((term, i) =>
    term == ''
      ? ''
      : `filters[$and][${i}][$or][0][Name][$containsi]=${term}
      &filters[$and][${i}][$or][1][Specialty][$containsi]=${term}
      &filters[$and][${i}][$or][2][City][$containsi]=${term}
  )
  .join('&');
```

Which yields a query that looks something like this:

```
"...
&filters[$and][0][$or][0][Name][$containsi]=TERM1
&filters[$and][0][$or][1][Specialty][$containsi]=TERM1
&filters[$and][0][$or][2][City][$containsi]=TERM1
&filters[$and][1][$or][0][Name][$containsi]=TERM2
&filters[$and][1][$or][1][Specialty][$containsi]=TERM2
&filters[$and][1][$or][2][City][$containsi]=TERM2"
```

Using this query, I am currently getting results that only include matches for the LAST FIELD specified. If I type a multi-word City name, like 'Grand Rapids', I get matches for Grand Rapids. Did I misread the solution I found, or was it not applicable to my case? What should I have to do here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You prolly want to use `qs` but I’m not sure if strapi supports more the one root level operator ($or, $and), you can feed the qs objects from entityService examples